# swift simple navigation controller not showing in view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

In my storyboard I added a View Controller then I embedded a Navigation controller like the following screen shot:

[image]

No code yet.  I set the Navigation Controller "Is Initial View Controller"

When I run the app it doesnt show the navigation.  It just shows:

[image]

I've followed tutorials and videos so im not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

OK this is weird.  I was able to solve the problem by doing the following.  I created another storyboard and re-added my code.  It seems like the original storyboard may have had issues with something.  I tried clean on the original with no luck.  Recreating it on another storyboard seems to have solved the issue